# React on DOM changes caused by Data Binding in Polymer

Tags: data-binding, dart, polymer

while exploring the pure awesomeness of Polymer and Dart I struggle to get some things animated right after they get inserted to the DOM by Data Binding.

**Example**:

```
<template repeat="{{item in items}}">
    <my-item item="{{item}}"></my-item>
</template>
```

Everytime a new item is inserted or an old one is removed I would like to animate these changes.

Currently I am doing something like this, which works but isn't really nice:

```
<style>
[item] { transition: 300ms ease-in-out; transform: translateX(0); ]
[require-start-animation] { transform: translateX(-100%); }
</style>
<template repeat="{{item in items}}">
    <my-item item="{{item}}" require-start-animation></my-item>
</template>
```

and before removing it, I add 'require-end-animation' to the elements which will be removed. 
The solution works but isn't really that great since I have to keep track of a lot of stuff such as adding the correct attributes at the correct time and removing it. React to transition ending and so on.

Thus I am asking you, is there a cleaner way to react on changes to the DOM which are caused by Data Binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a mixin which overrides `attached` and `detached` and does the attribute setting/removal before forwarding the call to super (the element itself) and then apply this mixin on elements you want to animate.

I haven't used mixins a lot myself yet. If mixins don't work well for this you could create an implementation in a normal class and then forward the calls to `attached` and `detached` to this implementation.

It could also work to create a wrapper element that just wraps the element you want to animate and implements the animation on attach/detach.

Comment: Great answer as always! Thanks a lot.